# Kotlin rest-assured collection matcher

Tags: kotlin, rest-assured, matcher

Could anyone help with right restassured matcher?
I have a custom error message, that is returned by rest controller advice. It contains a `meta` field, which stores object with `code` and `description`.

I'm writing a test, where i'm trying to check whether the right meta is present, so:

```
body("meta", hasItem(ErrorDto(code = "code", description = "description")))
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path meta doesn't match.
Expected: a collection containing <ErrorDto(code=code, 
description=description)>
  Actual: <[{code=code, description=description}]>
```

It seems that hasItem is not suitable at this case. I've tried to use other Matcher, but i get the same error...
P.S. the index approach works fine, but imho it's a little ugly...

```
body("meta[0].code", equalTo("code"))
body("meta[0].description", equalTo("description"))
```

I'm trying to solve this for few hours and i' completely stuck... Any ideas?

Comment: Because this is LinkedHashMap, not your ErrorDto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**
As far as I know, RestAssured will map

- array (json) <--> List (java)
- object (json) <--> LinkedHashMap (java)

Therefore, `body("meta")` --> return List of LinkedHashMap. You can't compare Object to LinkedHashMap.

**Solution:**

To make a list of ErrorDto, you need to tell RestAssured which type will be converted to.

Below is java version.

```
List<ErrorDto> list = response.jsonPath().getList("", ErrorDto.class);
```

Then you can use Hamcrest to assert

```
assertThat(list, hasItems(new ErrorDto("code", "description")));
```

Comment: Should fit, thank you!